# Change connector from "and" to "," in 'author' field, IEEEtranN bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using Natbib and I'm trying to make the authors in my bibliography appear like

```
Bryan Sullivan, Vincent Liu
```

but at the moment they appears like

```
Bryan Sullivan and Vincent Liu
```

I have tried using

```
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

but it's not working, it says that \multinamedelim doesn't exist.

I'm adding bibliography as so:

```
@book {
    WebApplicationSecurity,
    author = {{Bryan Sullivan} and {Vincent Liu}},
    title = {Web Application Security, a Beginner's Guide},
    publisher = {McGraw Hill},
    year = {2011}
}
```

I have also tried changing the "and" in this code to a comma, but then the second author disappears completely.

I'm compiling with XeLaTeX. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Formatting issues of the type you set out in your posting are governed not by `natbib`, which is for the most part a citation management system, but by the bibliography style that's being employed. Please do tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Here it is: \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm new to this (~1yr new to LaTeX, even newer bst) so please be kind, but I think I've got it:

Modify IEEEtranN.bst such that FUNCTION {format.names} reads:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  this.to.prev.status
  this.status.std
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      name.format.string
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { nameptr num.names.shown.with.forced.et.al #1 + =
          numnames max.num.names.before.forced.et.al >
          is.forced.et.al and and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft :=
            }
            { skip$ }
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t do.name.latex.cmd * }
            { s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " " * bbl.etal emphasize * }
                { numnames #2 >
                    { "," * }
                    { "," * } %%%%%%%%%%%%% added this line
                    %{ skip$ } %%%%%%%%%%%%% commented out this line
                  if$
                  %bbl.and %%%%%%%%%%%%% commented out this line
                  space.word * t do.name.latex.cmd *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t do.name.latex.cmd }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  cap.status.std
  } if$
}
```

This should change the name formatting, as shown below, for all types.
Hope that helps!

[image]

Edit: if you want the in text reference formatting to change as well as the bibliography formatting, follow the answer by @Mico : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506121/169285 (with a word of caution - it will also change 'format.lab.names' and I'm not entirely sure what this does).

Edit 2: MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Stuff happened \cite{WebApplicationSecurity}.

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I'm kind of in a hurry, so I don't really have time to test this now that I found a quicker (but probably worse) way to do it, which is just to code the author like author = {{Bryan Sullivan, Vincent Liu}},

Comment: @DavidAntelo - Rather than write `author = {{Bryan Sullivan, Vincent Liu}}`, it's much better to write `author = {Bryan Sullivan and Vincent Liu}`. That way, if you ever need to change bibliography styles, you don't have to do a lot of hand editing of the `author` fields of your bib entries. Please see [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506121/5001) I just posted for a completely different -- and, I dare say, better -- approach to formatting the `author` field.

Comment: It's not good advice to "[m]odify IEEEtranN.bst such that..." Original files of the TeX distribution should *never* be edited directly, if for no other reason than guarding against the chance that the file will get updated at some point in the future by the system, overwriting the changes you made. It's much better practice to start by making a copy of the bst file, renaming the copy, and making the required edits in the oopy only.

Comment: This answer looks interesting - but maybe it can be improved by including a screenshot of the result and/or a Minimal Working Example with Bibliography (MWEB) to make the answer easier to reproduce (for the asker but also for people that might find this answer at some point in the future).

Comment: I like @Mico's answer but it is doing things in a different way - it changes the definition of 'and', which means that it would change the in text reference as well as the bibliography formatting. 

'and' is also used in the definition of 'format.lab.names', which I'll be honest - I don't know what this does.

Comment: @Marijn - a screenshot I shall do, but a MWE would be a bit messy as I've editted the bst which is thousands of lines long. Open to any ideas.

Comment: @DannyGarside - The `IEEEtranN` bibliography style produces numeric-style in-text citation call-outs. Changing the value of the `bbl.and` function (from `"and"` to `"\unskip,"`) creates no issues with `and` no longer showing up in the in-text citation call-outs.

Comment: @DannyGarside I meant an MWE for the LaTeX file only, similar to the code in Mico's answer. I agree that the full `.bst` file would be too long, so for that it is necessary to describe which changes need to be made or just post the function itself, as you did.

Comment: @Mico - the version I'm using doesn't use numeric-style in-text citation call-outs (pulled from here: http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtranN.bst)... curious

Comment: @Marijn done! :)